# ssh command hangs indefinitely

Tags: ssh, ubuntu-18.04, openssh

I am trying to ssh into my ubuntu 18.04 remotely and my ssh command execution hangs after the password is authenticated. I have tried a lot of resolutions I found online but nothing has worked so far.

With the following command I get below output:

`ssh -vvvvv <user>@<IP>`

```
neha@10.151.193.90's password: 
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a password packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 52
debug1: Authentication succeeded (password).
Authenticated to 10.151.193.90 ([10.151.193.90]:22).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug3: ssh_session2_open: channel_new: 0
debug2: channel 0: send open
debug3: send packet: type 90
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug3: send packet: type 80
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: pledge: network
debug3: receive packet: type 80
debug1: client_input_global_request: rtype hostkeys-00@openssh.com want_reply 0
debug3: receive packet: type 91
debug2: channel_input_open_confirmation: channel 0: callback start
debug2: fd 3 setting TCP_NODELAY
debug3: ssh_packet_set_tos: set IP_TOS 0x10
debug2: client_session2_setup: id 0
debug2: channel 0: request pty-req confirm 1
debug3: send packet: type 98
debug1: Sending environment.
debug3: Ignored env CLUTTER_IM_MODULE
debug3: Ignored env CONDA_SHLVL
debug3: Ignored env LS_COLORS
debug3: Ignored env CONDA_EXE
debug3: Ignored env LESSCLOSE
debug3: Ignored env XDG_MENU_PREFIX
debug1: Sending env LANG = en_US.UTF-8
debug2: channel 0: request env confirm 0
debug3: send packet: type 98
debug3: Ignored env DISPLAY
debug3: Ignored env GNOME_SHELL_SESSION_MODE
debug3: Ignored env COLORTERM
debug3: Ignored env USERNAME
debug3: Ignored env XDG_VTNR
debug3: Ignored env SSH_AUTH_SOCK
debug3: Ignored env _CE_M
debug3: Ignored env XDG_SESSION_ID
debug3: Ignored env USER
debug3: Ignored env DESKTOP_SESSION
debug3: Ignored env QT4_IM_MODULE
debug3: Ignored env TEXTDOMAINDIR
debug3: Ignored env GNOME_TERMINAL_SCREEN
debug3: Ignored env PWD
debug3: Ignored env HOME
debug3: Ignored env CONDA_PYTHON_EXE
debug3: Ignored env TEXTDOMAIN
debug3: Ignored env SSH_AGENT_PID
debug3: Ignored env QT_ACCESSIBILITY
debug3: Ignored env XDG_SESSION_TYPE
debug3: Ignored env XDG_DATA_DIRS
debug3: Ignored env _CE_CONDA
debug3: Ignored env XDG_SESSION_DESKTOP
debug3: Ignored env GJS_DEBUG_OUTPUT
debug3: Ignored env GTK_MODULES
debug3: Ignored env WINDOWPATH
debug3: Ignored env TERM
debug3: Ignored env SHELL
debug3: Ignored env VTE_VERSION
debug3: Ignored env QT_IM_MODULE
debug3: Ignored env XMODIFIERS
debug3: Ignored env IM_CONFIG_PHASE
debug3: Ignored env XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP
debug3: Ignored env GPG_AGENT_INFO
debug3: Ignored env GNOME_TERMINAL_SERVICE
debug3: Ignored env XDG_SEAT
debug3: Ignored env SHLVL
debug3: Ignored env GDMSESSION
debug3: Ignored env GNOME_DESKTOP_SESSION_ID
debug3: Ignored env LOGNAME
debug3: Ignored env DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS
debug3: Ignored env XDG_RUNTIME_DIR
debug3: Ignored env XAUTHORITY
debug3: Ignored env XDG_CONFIG_DIRS
debug3: Ignored env PATH
debug3: Ignored env GJS_DEBUG_TOPICS
debug3: Ignored env SESSION_MANAGER
debug3: Ignored env LESSOPEN
debug3: Ignored env GTK_IM_MODULE
debug3: Ignored env _
debug2: channel 0: request shell confirm 1
debug3: send packet: type 98
debug2: channel_input_open_confirmation: channel 0: callback done
debug2: channel 0: open confirm rwindow 0 rmax 32768
debug3: receive packet: type 100
debug2: channel_input_status_confirm: type 100 id 0
PTY allocation request failed on channel 0
debug2: channel 0: rcvd adjust 2097152
debug3: receive packet: type 99
debug2: channel_input_status_confirm: type 99 id 0
debug2: shell request accepted on channel 0
```

I tried below command and got output as:

`ssh -vvvvv <user>@<IP> "/bin/bash -i"`

```
neha@10.151.193.90's password: 
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a password packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 52
debug1: Authentication succeeded (password).
Authenticated to 10.151.193.90 ([10.151.193.90]:22).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug3: ssh_session2_open: channel_new: 0
debug2: channel 0: send open
debug3: send packet: type 90
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug3: send packet: type 80
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: pledge: network
debug3: receive packet: type 80
debug1: client_input_global_request: rtype hostkeys-00@openssh.com want_reply 0
debug3: receive packet: type 91
debug2: channel_input_open_confirmation: channel 0: callback start
debug2: fd 3 setting TCP_NODELAY
debug3: ssh_packet_set_tos: set IP_TOS 0x08
debug2: client_session2_setup: id 0
debug1: Sending environment.
debug3: Ignored env CLUTTER_IM_MODULE
debug3: Ignored env CONDA_SHLVL
debug3: Ignored env LS_COLORS
debug3: Ignored env CONDA_EXE
debug3: Ignored env LESSCLOSE
debug3: Ignored env XDG_MENU_PREFIX
debug1: Sending env LANG = en_US.UTF-8
debug2: channel 0: request env confirm 0
debug3: send packet: type 98
debug3: Ignored env DISPLAY
debug3: Ignored env GNOME_SHELL_SESSION_MODE
debug3: Ignored env COLORTERM
debug3: Ignored env USERNAME
debug3: Ignored env XDG_VTNR
debug3: Ignored env SSH_AUTH_SOCK
debug3: Ignored env _CE_M
debug3: Ignored env XDG_SESSION_ID
debug3: Ignored env USER
debug3: Ignored env DESKTOP_SESSION
debug3: Ignored env QT4_IM_MODULE
debug3: Ignored env TEXTDOMAINDIR
debug3: Ignored env GNOME_TERMINAL_SCREEN
debug3: Ignored env PWD
debug3: Ignored env HOME
debug3: Ignored env CONDA_PYTHON_EXE
debug3: Ignored env TEXTDOMAIN
debug3: Ignored env SSH_AGENT_PID
debug3: Ignored env QT_ACCESSIBILITY
debug3: Ignored env XDG_SESSION_TYPE
debug3: Ignored env XDG_DATA_DIRS
debug3: Ignored env _CE_CONDA
debug3: Ignored env XDG_SESSION_DESKTOP
debug3: Ignored env GJS_DEBUG_OUTPUT
debug3: Ignored env GTK_MODULES
debug3: Ignored env WINDOWPATH
debug3: Ignored env TERM
debug3: Ignored env SHELL
debug3: Ignored env VTE_VERSION
debug3: Ignored env QT_IM_MODULE
debug3: Ignored env XMODIFIERS
debug3: Ignored env IM_CONFIG_PHASE
debug3: Ignored env XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP
debug3: Ignored env GPG_AGENT_INFO
debug3: Ignored env GNOME_TERMINAL_SERVICE
debug3: Ignored env XDG_SEAT
debug3: Ignored env SHLVL
debug3: Ignored env GDMSESSION
debug3: Ignored env GNOME_DESKTOP_SESSION_ID
debug3: Ignored env LOGNAME
debug3: Ignored env DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS
debug3: Ignored env XDG_RUNTIME_DIR
debug3: Ignored env XAUTHORITY
debug3: Ignored env XDG_CONFIG_DIRS
debug3: Ignored env PATH
debug3: Ignored env GJS_DEBUG_TOPICS
debug3: Ignored env SESSION_MANAGER
debug3: Ignored env LESSOPEN
debug3: Ignored env GTK_IM_MODULE
debug3: Ignored env _
debug1: Sending command: /bin/bash -i
debug2: channel 0: request exec confirm 1
debug3: send packet: type 98
debug2: channel_input_open_confirmation: channel 0: callback done
debug2: channel 0: open confirm rwindow 0 rmax 32768
debug2: channel 0: rcvd adjust 2097152
debug3: receive packet: type 99
debug2: channel_input_status_confirm: type 99 id 0
debug2: exec request accepted on channel 0
```

I also tried giving a command to ssh as below but it hanged at the same place as above:

`ssh -vvvvv <user>@<IP> "uptime"`

I have also tried unmounting and mounting /dev/pts but it didn't help. Also tried adding `UseDNS no` within sshd_config file but nothing changed. Tried creating another user on this host machine to verify if this could be some user specific issue but no luck. Tried passing the option  `ssh -o IPQoS=throughput ...` but it didn't help either.

Can anyone point me what possibly could be an issue here.

Comment: Stackoverflow is for help with software development. You should consider asking questions like this on [ubuntu.se], [unix.se], or [su].

Comment: Thanks. I have now posted it on askubuntu.